# Run Windows 7 Services on Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, compatibility

I have a working application that is deployed to all our Win 7 PC's across a national network. This application uses a 3rd party SDK from Brother printers.

We now have the situation where the new Win 8 PC's won't run the application as the SDK / assemblies from Brother are not Win 8 Compatible (and currently they have no plan to make them compatible).

Is there any way I can set up a service or an exe to run in Win 7 Mode, like you could do in Win 7 for XP programs?

Comment: You mean Windows 7 mode like Windows XP mode in Windows 7 for Windows 8? You can install a virtual machine for this, right?

Comment: You could use VirtualBox, VMWare Workstation, or the Microsoft Virtual PC can't you?

Comment: We could use a vm you are right, but some of these pc's will be run by 'less technically able users', and any OS hosted in a vm will need a windows 7 license, suddenly making these particular workstations very expensive.

Comment: Have you tried just setting it to be run in compatibility mode for Windows 7? It almost seems too easy for that to work, though...

Comment: What is the brother SDK name/link/download?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. In the end We decided to remove all win 8 instances and go back to win 7. Guess we are waiting for win 9 now, working on the assumption that MS does a good OS then a bad one 8-)